# Oracle AQ Asynchronous notification

Tags: oracle10g, oracle-aq

I'm planning to make use of Oracle AQ Asynchronous notification feature in an OLTP application.The number of messages it enqueues might go up to 1000 within a minute during peak hours. The dequeue callback procedure will process the message and inserts an entry into a table which is determined by the type of message.

My concern is that, does the large number of enqueue notifications it generates(the PL/SQL callback procedure that is being called in turn for every notification) cause database contention ? 
Is it advisable to use Asynchronous notification for this purpose or Should I go with dequeue polling process where I can dequeue one message a time in a continous loop.

My database version is 10gR2

Your expert help is highly appreciated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each message enqueued into the queue, ORACLE background process invokes the related callback procedure by creating a scheduler job. 
As you are expecting 1000 messages with in a minute if you depend on the callback procedure it increases the load on ORACLE background processes and also creates those many onetime scheduler jobs, again if the no.of parallel scheduler jobs created is more than the "job_queue_processes" (ORACLE parameter) value configured in your database that delays the message processing, instead if you choose for polling to dequeue by using AQ listener, a single job can process all the messages enqueued in to the queue.

Comment: Well, for the manual dequeue process, Is it advisable to submit a one-time scheduler job that runs 24*7 (holding up 1 job slot) and have the procedure run the dequeue command in waiting mode in an infinite loop ? Are there any better solutions for running the dequeue process continuosly in the background ?

Comment: One infinite loop job is not a good option as the procedure continuously runs, even though there are no messages to dequeue...

Instead create a procedure which uses dbms_aq listeners in a loop to dequeue the messages from the queue. The listener allows you to dequeue the message if there are any messages in the queue, else it throws a LISTENER TIME_OUT exception... use the exception to come out of the loop..so that procedure runs only when there is atleast one message in the queue.

you can create one or more no.of jobs based on your requirement for this procedure.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!
As I understand, the procedure having the AQ listener command should be executed through a scheduler job that runs 24*7 to listen for messages. 
Even with this approach, the job is going to occupy 1 permenant slot and run continously. Am i understanding it wrong ? Could you please elaborate it a bit more ? Is there a way we can avoid running a continuous job ? BTW, as with my approach, the dequeue command runs in waiting mode inside the loop. If there are no messages, it simply waits until a message arrives. I guess this is similar to LISTEN blocking call.

Comment: I mean, schedule jobs with a specific interval (say 10sec), this job will continues to process if there are any messages in the queue, once it completes processing of all the messages it comes out of the loop by throwing a LISTER_TIME_OUT exception and it repeats the same process after the scpecified interval.